# Set credentials when using ntlm (kerberos) authentication

Tags: c++, winhttp

I have a c++ application which using NTLM authentication method (WinHttpSetOption). what I'm trying to do is to set the credentials, meaning: the NTLM uath is using the logged on credentials, I want to provide him the credentials myself (in `domain\user` format).

From the MSDN I see that the `WinHttpSetCredentials` doesn't affect.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `WinHttpSetOption` using `WINHTTP_OPTION_AUTOLOGON_POLICY`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384066.aspx#WINHTTP_OPTION_AUTOLOGON_POLICY

If you set the value to `WINHTTP_AUTOLOGON_SECURITY_LEVEL_HIGH`, then it stops WinHttp from providing default credentials and you can set it yourself when you receive the proper 401/407 response using `WinHttpSetCredentials`.